# Segue not passing correct indexpath of row always section 0

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7, uistoryboardsegue

I'm used sectioned tableView.If I click tableview always it passing indexpath 0 to detail view controller.If I click second row but it indexpath pass always pass 0.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toNext"]) {
    detailTableViewController *detailVC = [segue destinationViewController];
    [detailVC setkMessageDict:(NSDictionary*)[nArray objectAtIndex:[self.mytableView indexPathForSelectedRow].section]];
}
```

What's wrong in code?

Comment: How many sections are there ? Maybe you mean row not section.

Comment: i have 4 section..always It returns 0. @KudoCC

Comment: @gagarwal can you provide some example?

Comment: @gagarwal Please edit with my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toNext"]) {
    NSIndexPath *selectedIndex= [self.mytableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSDictionary *myDic=(NSDictionary*)[nArray objectAtIndex:indexpath.section];
    detailTableViewController *detailVC = [segue destinationViewController];
    [detailVC setkMessageDict:(NSDictionary*)[[myDic objectForKey:@"locations"] objectAtIndex:selectedIndex.row]];
}
```

Please check your Array having the proper data from your section tableview otherwise add the `NSDictionary` value to array and pass it to `detailTableViewController` then try.Problem is your are not passing indexpath of section here.Hope its helpful for you.

Comment: still the same.Can you pls give some more sample

Comment: Pls add me in skype..Got it my id?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create **index-path** object in to your seque like:-

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"toNext" sender:indexPath];
}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableview indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSLog(@" indexPath row %d",indexPath.row);
    NSLog(@" indexPath row %d",indexPath.section);
    detailTableViewController *detailVC = [segue destinationViewController];
    [detailVC setJobDetailDict:(NSDictionary*)[nArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes Ramdy, is right You need to mention row instead of section.
You use this....

```
[detailVC setJobDetailDict:(NSDictionary*)[nArray objectAtIndex:[self.mytableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row]];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString * currentRow = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row];  // Declare this row variable in .h file
    NSString * currentSection = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld",(long)indexPath.section];  // Declare this section variable in .h file
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toNext"]) {
    detailTableViewController *detailVC = [segue destinationViewController];    
    detailVC.PassRow = currentRow;
    detailVC.PassSection = currentSection;
}
```

Comment: If I change row it passing all the first row of  each section only. @Ramdy

Comment: PassRow and PassSection is what kind of property? @Ramdy

Comment: I have to declare as a string in detailView?

Comment: its just NSString , declare in detailTableViewController.

Comment: from prapareForSegue, we are sending only row and section. Just use nslog("%@ %@",passrow,passsection); to print value, just check it out , before that these passrow , passsection should be a property and synthesized.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating the selected row indexPath using API:

```
selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:
```

in the following UITableViewDelegate API:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Answer (score 0):

The closest answer to the question is **Nitin Gohel**. But if you have connected the `UITableViewCell` to the `detailTableViewController` in the **Storyboard**, his method is also **wrong.**

In that case, the `prepareForSegue` method is provided with the correct `UITableViewCell` as a parameter stored in the `sender` parameter. This is entirely handled by `UITableView`. So the correct code would be:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]] && [segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"toNext"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.mytableView indexPathForCell:sender];

        detailTableViewController *detailVC = [segue destinationViewController];
        [detailVC setJobDetailDict:(NSDictionary*)[nArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

**Do not forget to check for correct segue name.**

Comment: Thanks for your answer.still same issue Always passing first cell row value of each section